# How do I get the GCC __attribute__ ((constructor)) to work under OSX?

Tags: c, macos, gcc

```
extern void MyInitFunc(void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
extern void MyTermFunc(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));

void MyInitFunc(void)
{
  printf("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\n");
}

void MyTermFunc(void)
{
}
```

I put this in a .c file which is present in the main application (not a library or framework). It doesn't get called as per the GCC docs. Am I missing something important? This is on XCode 3.2 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: As it happens, my answer below was really not very helpful (no actual solution given) so I'm not expecting you to accept it, but you seem to have received fine answers for at least some of your other 7 questions. Why haven't you accepted any answers?

Comment: They seem to have vanished. I accepted a couple today again but the badge still doesn't update itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Your code works for me compiling and running on SnowLeopard in Xcode 3.2.

(b) I'm not sure when stdout is guaranteed to have been set up.  You're running code before main.  Why not update a global variable here, then print it out in main to see if your code ran.

Comment: Not sure why this didn't work the first time. I added a new source file with the initializers, made sure it was the first file in the compile sources step, and now it works. Being the first item after the crt in the load map it loads before any of the c++ static initializers.

Answer (score 9):

This might explain some of the strange bugs being reported on Snow Leopard, but only if this construct worked in earlier releases.

You are correct that `MyInitFunc` should have been called purely as a result of being linked in with the program, even if the program is plain C89, even if the rest of it is some other language entirely.

The problem is that the C startup code on your system is not looking at the `.ctors` section and the `.dtors` section for addresses of constructors and destructors. I'm not sure if this is true of all platforms, but normally this is `__do_global_ctors`, a part of `libgcc`.

It's a platform bug, or, your gcc was built wrong, or, Apple has simply decided to do things differently and gcc doesn't support the platform properly.

You might try `cc -v ...` and check that `collect2` is being called instead of `ld` directly.

Comment: I haven't tried on Snow Leopard, but I do recall using this functionality on older Mac OS Xen.

Comment: It is documented in a technote as working and mentioned in a document I just found: Dynamic Library Programming Topics. Maybe something will click in there.

Comment: It says "Note: Applications can also define and use initializer and finalizers."

Comment: It doesn't mention what extra requirement is there for an application. I may have to build a  library.

Comment: Are you not using Mac OS X?  I think you're giving reasons why it could fail, not why this person is having problems.  It works fine for me.