# How to emulate constructor or static block in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, static, constructor

I am enhancing a tool.
Please note that this tool will be linked to test program, which will have `main( )` function, so my tool can't have main. What this tool has is a number of functions which the test program will use.

Now additionally, i want to add a timer to this tool. The idea is: when the test program is linked to this tool and starts, the timer should automatically start.

If this was C++, i would have created a class with a constructor, so that whenever the class is loaded, the constructor is called first, and i can initialize my timer inside the constructor.

If this was Java, i would have simply created a global static block, and put the timer code inside the static block.

But my tool is purely in C in Linux, so how can i achieve this goal?

Please help me.

Comment: Is your tool a shared library ?

Comment: How is the tool `linked` with the test program?

Comment: I'd say by documenting that on startup of `main()` the user has to call function `X` to use your library.

Comment: @nos and @pascal: Yes, we have both a static (ar) and a shared library, for this tool. The user has the freedom to link his test program either statically or via the shared library as per his choice.

Comment: @RedX: No this will violate the design, the tool is similar to a memory tracking tool, so the only thing user can do is to link it, he cannot call any function from the code.

Comment: @kingsmasher1, follow the C++ or java designs, they BOTH need some initialization (in java the class needs to be loaded, in case it is not obvious). In your case if there is any function called, init whatever necessary there, check a flag, use mutex/CAS, etc..

Comment: @bestsss: The `init` how to get it itself, was the problem my friend, but i have got the answer now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like your case also:

[How do I get the GCC __attribute__ ((constructor)) to work under OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526882/how-do-i-get-the-gcc-attribute-constructor-to-work-under-osx)

From GCC docs:

> constructor
>   destructor
>   constructor (priority)
>   destructor (priority)
>
> The constructor attribute causes the
>   function to be called automatically
>   before execution enters main ().
>   Similarly, the destructor attribute
>   causes the function to be called
>   automatically after main () has
>   completed or exit () has been called.
>   Functions with these attributes are
>   useful for initializing data that will
>   be used implicitly during the
>   execution of the program.

Comment: @kinsmachert This seems to be what you want. Here are the docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: @RedX and vines: Thanks,let me check it and get back to you very shortly.

Comment: @RedX, oh yes, I should have provided the link too :)

Comment: @RedX and vines: Yes, exactly this is what i wanted. Thanks to vines and RedX. RedX, wish you could also have put an answer, so that i could have accepted / upvoted :)

Comment: Note that this only works for shared libraries, not static libraries

Answer (score 2):

Write your own replacement for the `crt*.o` object file that calls `main()`, and link to it when building.

Comment: The test program will also call it's own library, where there will be crti, crto etc, so if i do that, the actual one will be overwritten giving undesirable results.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it would be overwritten. They're statically linked, so if you don't want to use them then just don't link against them.

Comment: Our test program, is actually a huge-huge code run on multiple platforms [incl. x86 :) ], We can't restrict the user, to not use their own crt's as that will be a limitation. I think vines and RedX's solution will be useful, and thanks to you too, we can consider this as an alternate solution. So i have upvoted your answer too.